# Winetricks fails installing dotnet20 and msxml6

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine, winetricks

I tried installing dotnet20 and msxml6 with winetricks, but both fail with different errors.

It seems that ***dotnetfx20*** isn't available anymore at the microsoft download center.
Here's my output for the command `winetricks dotnet20`:

```
LinuxSchnitzel Downloads # winetricks dotnet20
Executing w_do_call dotnet20
Executing load_dotnet20
Executing w_do_call fontfix
Executing load_fontfix
Setting Windows version to win2k
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_dotnet20\set-winver.reg
Executing mkdir -p /root/.cache/winetricks/dotnet20
Executing unzip -o -q -d /root/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/syswow64 l_intl.zip
Executing mkdir -p /root/.cache/winetricks/dotnet20
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/7/567758a3-759e-473e-bf8f-52154438565a/dotnetfx.exe to /root/.cache/winetricks/dotnet20
--2012-08-16 19:30:03--  http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/7/567758a3-759e-473e-bf8f-52154438565a/dotnetfx.exe
Resolving download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)... 80.239.221.105, 80.239.221.91
Connecting to download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)|80.239.221.105|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-08-16 19:30:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.

------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/7/567758a3-759e-473e-bf8f-52154438565a/dotnetfx.exe failed
------------------------------------------------------
```

So, what do I do now? I tried installing [.Net Framework 2.0 SP1 x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6041) manually, but that fails either with no specific error message.

***msxml6*** is apparently available but it fails. A message dialog tells me, that msxml6 isn't made for 64-bit. How do I configure wine to get the 64-bit packages?
Output:

```
LinuxSchnitzel Downloads # winetricks msxml6
Executing w_do_call msxml6
Executing load_msxml6
Executing mkdir -p /root/.cache/winetricks/msxml6
Using native,builtin override for following DLLs: msxml6
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_msxml6\override-dll.reg
Executing wine msiexec /i /root/.cache/winetricks/msxml6/msxml6_x86.msi
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"LaunchConditions" returned 1603
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command 'wine msiexec /i /root/.cache/winetricks/msxml6/msxml6_x86.msi' returned status 67.  Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to install MS Office 2010 x86. Do I need to configure wine for 64-bit?

**Update:**
I managed to install msxml6. To be able to do that, I had to rename ~/.wine to something else and recreate the wine config with `$ WINEARCH=win32 winecfg`.
Installing msxml6 worked without problems then.

**Update2:**
Now that I've set wine to run in 32-bit mode, I was able to download dotnetfx.exe from [filehippo](http://www.filehippo.com/de/download_dotnet_framework_2/496/) and ran it with `$ wine dotnetfx.exe`.
Sadly, the installation failed:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem yesterday. I posted a fix on the ubuntu forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12176837

Maybe that works better than the file from filehippo.

Edit: Make sure that wine is in 32 bit mode as specified on the wine-hq page for .net 2.0

Comment: Note: to run wine in 32-bit mode, one has to delete ~/.wine and run `WINEARCH=win32 winecfg`. All installed applications will be lost then, so backup your .wine directory.

Comment: This is not correct. You can specify WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-32 and then run wineboot. Then you will have a 64 and 32 bit version of WINE. Depending on what your environment variables are only one of those is used.

Comment: Actually that is not correct. WINEPREFIX specifies what folder to use for the wine prefix, and is needed whenever running a program in that prefix.  WINEARCH specifies what arch to use when creating a prefix, and is only used at prefix creation.